# Change date format in Laravel migration

Tags: laravel-6, laravel-migrations

I want to change the date format from `1990-01-30` to `30/01/1990` straight from my migration. I get the following error when I try to migrate with seeding from factory.

> Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '30/01/1990' for
>   column 'dob' at row 1

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('fname');
        $table->string('lname');
        $table->string('phone')->unique();
        $table->date('dob')->format('d/m/Y');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Formatting a date is usually done at the application layer - definitely not in the DB.  I am pretty sure there is no way to specify a format for a date col in MySQL, at least.  Neither is there any mention of `format()` modifier in [the Laravel migration docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#columns).  My guess is your `format()` is simply being ignored, and a normal `date` col is being created.  Best solution would be to [`cast` your date to the format you want](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-mutators#date-casting).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare in model:

```
class ModelName extends Model
{      

 protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:d/m/Y', // Change your format
    'updated_at' => 'datetime:d/m/Y',
];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that within a migration. You will need to use Carbon and format the date in your Model instead.

Comment: i used this `'dob' => Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '01/01/1990')->format('d/m/Y'),` in my factory. This is able to change the date format in the factory but the structure of the database still remains this format (Y-m-d), hence giving this error

`Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '30/01/1990' for column 'dob' at row 1`